# Drools KieContainer returns null KieSession

Tags: drools, kie

I'm trying to run the examples from the Drools documentation. I have the following code.

```
KieServices kieServices = KieServices.Factory.get();
KieContainer kieContainer = kieServices.getKieClasspathContainer("droolspoc");
KieSession kieSession = kieContainer.newKieSession("HelloWorld");

kieSession.addEventListener(new DebugAgendaEventListener());
kieSession.addEventListener(new DebugRuleRuntimeEventListener());

// Create the fact
final Message message = new Message("Hello World", Message.HELLO);
kieSession.insert(message);

kieSession.fireAllRules();
```

The kieContainer.newKieSession always returns null. I found some discussion about needing an XML configuration file for the session. None of that is mentioned in the example.

I added a kmodule.xml file to my classpath with this in it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kmodule xmlns="http://www.drools.org/xsd/kmodule"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <kbase name="droolspoc" packages="rules">
        <ksession name="HelloWorld"/>
    </kbase>
</kmodule>
```

I am still getting a null session. Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you sure that it's actually reading the file? I've always put the kmodule.xml in a META-INF folder on my classpath (eg with maven `src/main/resources/META-INF/kmodule.xml`). There's nothing wrong with the kmodule.xml you've included in your question.

Comment: That did it. If you want to move your comment to an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `kmodule.xml` file needs to be inside of a folder called `META-INF` on your classpath.

If this were a maven project, you'd therefore want your XML file to be located at `src/main/resources/META-INF/kmodule.xml`. If using another build system or manually configuring your classpath, make sure that the META-INF path exists.

Note also that the rule packages described in your `kbase` definitions are relative to the classpath root, not relative to `META-INF`. So if you describe your kbase like `<kbase name="foo" packages="rules.foo.fun">`, then your rule files should be located at `<classpath>/rules/foo/fun`.